# Как вытащить определенный елемент в массиве?

Tags: php

Есть многомернный массив

```
array(3) { 
  'base' => string(3) "AUD" 
  'rates' => array(1) { 
    'EUR' => double(0.6335128286) 
   } 
   'date' => string(10) "2019-04-10" 
}
```

Как мне вытащить в подмассиве `rates` всегда первое значения ?
Я сделал так:

```
$rate  = json_decode($response, true);
$value = array_slice($rate, 1,1);
$first = array_shift($value);
$str   = implode($first);
```

Может есть более простой вариант ?

Comment: что значит _"вытащить"_? удалить из массива, или просто получить значение? `current($obj['rates'])` даст вам то единственное значение из `rates` без знания ключа

Comment: просто получить значения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У каждого массива есть внутренний указатель на текущий элемент. Когда вы только получили массив, этот указатель будет указывать на первый элемент. Функции `current()` и `key()` получают значение и ключ текущего элемента соответственно.

Поэтому для массива:

```
$data = [
    'base' => "AUD",
    'rates' => [
        'EUR' => 0.63,
    ],
    'date' => '2019-04-10',
];
```

значение `0.63` можно получив просто с помощью

```
echo current($data['rates']);
```